# Deserialization of json string returns null values

Tags: c#, json

how can I deserialize the ff json string:

```
{"stock":[{"name":"stock1","price":{"currency":"AUD","amount":103.50},"percent_change":-1.33,"volume":1583760,"symbol":"SC1"}],"as_of":"2016-06-10T15:20:00+08:00"}
```

I've tried the code:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<stock>(content);
```

where content variable is the json string above. 
However I am getting null value of the properties.

Here are my classes:

```
public class price
{
    public string currency { get; }

    public double amount { get; }
}


public class stock
{
    public string name { get; }

    public price price { get; }

    public double percent_change { get; }

    public int volume { get; }

    public string symbol { get; }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this class for your json string-

```
public class Price
{
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public double amount { get; set; }
}

public class Stock
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Price price { get; set; }
    public double percent_change { get; set; }
    public int volume { get; set; }
    public string symbol { get; set; }
}

public class StockDetails
{
    public List<Stock> stock { get; set; }
    public string as_of { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a setter:

public string name { get; set; }

-- update --

You are putting a list of stock into stock.

Add the class:

```
public class container
{
    public List<stock> Stock { get; set; }
    public string as_of { get; set; }
}
```

And call:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<container>(content);
```

Comment: hello, I did it to all properties but I still get null values.